# Serve the following static resources from a domain that doesn't set cookies

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies, cookieless

I have a specific question regarding satisfying the Pingdom Tools criteria of "Serve the following static resources from a domain that doesn't set cookies".

My situation is quite specific and I've googled extensively, followed multiple guides and even went as far as asking my hosting provider but didn't get help there (which I assumed).

This is my scenario:

I have a website called "www.wheretofarminwow.com" and I've run the speed test at tools.pingdom.com and I get the "Serve the following static resources from a domain that doesn't set cookies" message.

I've moved the static files from wheretofarminwow.com to another site wtfiwstatic.com

And I assumed that domain "www.wtfiwstatic.com" would be cookieless because it doesn't doesn't do anything but just host those static files, but I keep on getting that "Serve the following static resources from a domain that doesn't set cookies" message from Pingdom.

I've even added a htaccess rule on that domain to try to not set any cookies:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Hoping the bright community at Stack overflow could give me some insight on my situation and perhaps guide me to achieve my goal.

Thanking in advance,

Johnny

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

It turns out as I was using Cloudflare on wtfiwstatic.com, Cloudflare sets a cookie to every request for security reasons and can't be disabled. Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Sources:

https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains/

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169816-Can-I-serve-a-cookieless-domain-or-subdomain-through-Cloudflare-